# Wp Super Cache stops the update of a Post Meta

Tags: theme-development, post-meta, plugin-wp-supercache

For a custom 'Most popular posts' widget, I created a function that creates/updates a post meta to save the number of posts views and I included this function in the `single.php` template.

It works just fine till I installed WP Super Cache, the number of views stay unchanged.

How can I use this function with the WP Super Cache activated?

This is the function included in the `single.php`:

```
function save_views($postID){
  $metakey = 'postsViews';
  $views = get_post_meta($postID,$metakey,true);
  $count = (empty($views) ? 0 : $views);
  $count++;
  update_post_meta($postID,$metakey,$count);
}
remove_action('wp_head','adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head',10,0);
```

Comment: could you brief how you invoke the `save_views` method in your `functions.php` file?

Comment: 1. it is a bad idea to do statistics on the same server as the site. 2. obviously you can not do it this way if the server is not invoked.

Comment: @MariaDanielDeepak I invoke it on the single.php template

Comment: @Elidrissi simo Yeap, I got that. But on which hook?

Comment: @Mark Kaplun, May I know the reason for this - "It is a bad idea to do statistics on the same server as the site".

Comment: @MariaDanielDeepak i invoke it directly without any hook

Comment: @MariaDanielDeepak because DB writes should be avoided from front end as they are much more expensive than reads and slow down the DB and therefor the server. Imagine having a lot of traffic and if for each page view you write to the DB, sooner then later you going to crash the DB. You can do all kinds of things (write to file, not the DB) to make the chance of that happening smaller, but in the end, statistics are a nice to have and there is no good reason to even have the chance of them bringing down the site. If you can not use GA, use a different server for them

Comment: @Mark Kaplun That makes total sense. However, the jQuery script in this case, is going to execute only once per page load and I don't think that's a heavy load to the server.

Comment: @Elidrissi simo From the looks of it, the function `save_views` is only defined and not invoked. That's why I commented in first place.

Comment: Yes this is just the definition of the function invoked in single.php

Comment: @MariaDanielDeepak I saw **read** ajax requests done on each page load (some social sharing plugin) bring down a site. granted you might be able to have it working for a long time until you start having good traffic, but that is exactly when you do not want to start restructuring your site :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using WP Super Cache, the plugin generates static HTML files for your templates, which means that any PHP code you're running will only ever run when the cached page is generated or regenerated.

So if you need to trigger PHP code on every page load from behind a cache, you'll need to use [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

So for your use case you'll need two functions added to your functions file. Firstly you'll need to add the Javascript that makes the AJAX request to the footer of all of your posts. This will do that:

```
function my_count_views_script() {
    if ( is_single() ) :
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery.post({
                url:     '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                action:  'my_count_views',
                post_id: <?php the_ID(); ?>
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_count_views_script' );
```

This sends a request to the admin-ajax.php file with the post_id of the post being viewed and the action we want to perform with it.

To count this view, you need to tell admin-ajax.php what code to run when it received a request with the `my_count_views` action. You do this by hooking onto `wp_ajax_my_count_views` (to handle it for logged in users) and `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_count_views` for logged out users:

```
function my_count_views() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) && $_POST['post_id'] ) {
        $post_id = intval( $_POST['post_id'] );
        $views = intval( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'postsViews', true ) ) ?: 0;
        $views += 1;

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'postsViews', $views );
    }

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_count_views', 'my_count_views' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_count_views', 'my_count_views' );
```

Comment: I have suggested couple of edits to improve security and also to keep JS isolated from PHP for easier maintenance.

Comment: You basically remove most of the advantages of using caching in the first place.... might as well just not use the caching at all

Comment: .... only situation this might make sense is if you use a CDN with long expiry.

Comment: How is that remotely true? Most of the advantages of using a cache removed? This doesn't remove any of the advantages, it's just a tiny script quietly pops off a request in the background, and doesn't interfere with the performance advantages of a cache at all.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, each ajax request will do in this case two DB reads (options and post data) which assuming you do not have any complex widget or shortcode on the post page is exactly the number of requests that will be done when generating the HTML  Assuming some complex HTML generation, you might end up with x10 performance improvement instead of x1000 you expect to get when using a cache, and I am being generous here as there is also the overhead of server handling of the request and booting wordpress, and who knows what kind of shenanigans other plugin do on startup.

Comment: ..... wordpress ajax (and rest api) have very bad performance in general, atleast much worse then you might naively assume.

Comment: .... one of the things that ajax requests suck in, is that they run under admin context which means they load all that is required to handle admin request, so the minimum here is not to use the ajax end point, but instead define a json route and use it instead

Comment: Mate the AJAX request isn't rendering anything. It's firing off in the background, from the footer after the page has already loaded. It's not going to affect the speed at all.

You seem to be under the impression that the widget is being rendered with Ajax, but it's not. It will just get refreshed whenever the cache refreshes. The Ajax request is just for handling the view.

Comment: Thank you very much it works.but i used jquery.ajax() instead.